# Как добавить Web-видеоплееру переключение аудио дорожек из контейнера видео .mkv

Tags: javascript, html

Подключил через  фильм в контейнере .mkv с тремя аудио дорожками на разных языках. Порядок индексов аудио дорожек в самом контейнере видео такой: Японский, Русский(установлен по-умолчанию для плееров), Английский. На сайте же включается видео с японской дорожкой. Гуглил долго, в итоге просто по теме встроенных аудио дорожек **нашел только** пример с **AudioTrackList (JS)**, и то, работает только в Internet Explorer и **нужной функции не выполняет**. Подскажите, как можно управлять аудио дорожками в контейнере(может посредством изменения тех же индексов через JS или лучше языка)?

Буду очень благодарен за рабочий пример кода